# USB stick bad superblock. Works absolutely fine in Windows

Tags: 10.04, usb, filesystem, usb-drive, fsck

When I plug in my 8GB Cruzer Blade 8GB (Formatted as FAT32) into my Ubuntu computer, I get a mount error. The command 'e2fsck -f /dev/sda1" gives me "Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1". Using a backup superblock gives the same thing.

Problem is, it works fine on Windows.

Comment: Use `fsck.vfat` for checking a FAT filesystem, not `e2fsck`. Use the `badblocks` command to scan the 'surface' of the USB stick.

Comment: FAT32/VFAT *does not* use superblocks -- those are an EXT2/3/4 feature.

Answer (score 2):

You're applying the command `e2fsck`, which operates on an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem, to a FAT32 filesystem. Unsurprisingly, `e2fsck` complains that it doesn't find a valid ext[234] filesystem.

If you want to check that filesystem, run `fsck` (which will determine the proper utility for the filesystem on that device) or invoke the proper utility directly (`fsck.vfat`).

If you still get a mount error, copy-paste the error message. Note that Linux's filesystem driver is sometimes more picky about damaged media than Windows's. If you think the stick might be damaged, copy the data off it with [ddrescue](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ddrescue) [image: Install ddrescue]:

```
sudo ddrescue /dev/sda1 /var/tmp/sda1
```

You can then mount the files in the image with

```
sudo mount -o loop,ro,umask=022 /var/tmp/sda1 /mnt
```

By the way, is `/dev/sda` really your stick? Usually `/dev/sda` is the first internal disk.